# Download photos in android when scrolling down

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, download

I have created an app which displays photos in a `gridview` and I want to load the photos from internet as the user scrolls up (like the `pinterest` app and `facebook` app), how can I make this?

The website exports a list of images and the app must load that in background and display the images as the user scrolls up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one the images will be loaded from server, for efficient you need to implement LazyLoad Adapter

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

use this Links this will help to image loading http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html or https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-BitmapCache